In cpp, what is way to fix err "use of deleted function ‘Ort::Value::Value(const Ort::Value&)"
I use following code
const Ort::Value &img_file_to_tensor(std::string input_img_path) {
    // Load the image using OpenCV
    cv::Mat input_mat = cv::imread(input_img_path);

    // Convert to float
    cv::cvtColor(input_mat, input_mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    input_mat.convertTo(input_mat, CV_32F);
    // Normalize

    input_mat /= 255.0;
    // Convert the preprocessed image to a vector of floats
    Ndarray<float> input_img = mat_to_ndarray(input_mat);

//    std::string r = xarr_to_str(xa);
    input_img.transpose({2, 0, 1});
//    const std::string &xa_str1 = xarr_to_str(xa);
//    std::cout << xa_str1 << std::endl;
    input_img.expand_dims(0);
//    const std::string &xa_str2 = xarr_to_str(xa);
//    std::cout << xa_str2 << std::endl;

    auto input_vector = input_img.data;
    auto input_shape = input_img.shape;

    Ort::MemoryInfo memoryInfo = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu(OrtAllocatorType::OrtArenaAllocator,
                                                            OrtMemType::OrtMemTypeDefault);
    // Create the input tensor
    const Ort::Value &tensor = Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
            memoryInfo,
            input_vector.data(),
            input_vector.size(),
            input_shape.data(),
            input_shape.size());
    return tensor;
}

and call it
auto tensor = img_file_to_tensor(input_img_path);

above call code raise err:
error: use of deleted function ‘Ort::Value::Value(const Ort::Value&)’
   23 |     auto tensor = img_file_to_tensor(input_img_path);

I think the reason is: when return, Ort::Value mem will be removed, so what is way to create tensor in meth to prevent this err

The error is telling you that Ort::Value does not have a usable copy constructor, but you are trying to make a copy in this statement:
auto tensor = img_file_to_tensor(input_img_path);

As auto will be deduced as Ort::Value not Ort::Value& as you are expecting. auto does not deduce references.  If you want a reference, you have to be explicit, ie:
const auto &tensor = img_file_to_tensor(input_img_path);

However, CreateTensor() returns a new Ort::Value by value. It is a temporary object. You are extending the lifetime of that temporary when you initialize your tensor reference variable using that temporary. The temporary remains alive only while that tensor reference remains in scope. Once you reach your return statement, the tensor reference goes out scope, thus the Ort::Value object goes out of scope and is destroyed, and you return a dangling reference, which is undefined behavior.  You simply can't return a reference to a temporary.
Fortunately, Ort::Value does support move semantics (ie, it has a move constructor and a move assignment operator), so there is no need to return the temporary by reference. You can return it by value instead, and let the compiler move it for you (no need to use std::move in this example):
Ort::Value img_file_to_tensor(std::string input_img_path) {
    ...
    return Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
            memoryInfo,
            input_vector.data(),
            input_vector.size(),
            input_shape.data(),
            input_shape.size());
}

auto tensor = img_file_to_tensor(input_img_path);


I use std::move but return value and Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float> in main value still diff, how to make return value same with main create tensor value

They will be different objects, but they should refer to the same value. If that is not the case then you need to explain what is actually different between them.
